# How to get the config file name Apache kafka is using

Tags: apache-kafka

So there are file(s) in config folder for Kafka server like "server.properties"
We can use any name here instead of "server.properties". Example - "server-1.properties",etc.

My question is that is there any way to find out which configuration files Apache Kafka is using currently? Like if there is some command to show the current running config files.

Comment: Kafka dumps the whole config into the log. Use diff to find a line in the config files that differs and check what was dumped out.

Comment: On Linux, `ps -ef | grep Kafka`, and parse through the process list

Comment: @cricket_007 What if there are 3 config files say - server1.properties, server2.properties and server3.properties. Only server1 and server2 are running but I want all of them?

Comment: @Harald I need the config file names for automation task.  Logs won't help if I'm running it for the first time.

Comment: Not sure why you would run more than one broker on a single machine... That isn't really helpful in performance for disk and memory usages.... Still, you need to know where that file is stored... There is no Kafka command to get this information, but as mentioned, the logs *will **output*** the broker config when "runnning it for the first time"